# Edittext: set right icon size

Tags: android, android-edittext

I am using following code to set right icon: `editTex.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(0, 0, R.drawable.icon_valid, 0);`

Icon size is 12*12 which looks smaller.I need to set it to 24*24 at least. I tried using:

```
Drawable dr = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.somedrawable);
Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable) dr).getBitmap();
Drawable d = new BitmapDrawable(getResources(), Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, 24, 24, true));
```

But `setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds` gets input parameter as `int` not `Drawable`

Answer (score 0):

set dimensions into dimens.xml file in res/values